# Homotopy monoidal structure from Hirsch Algebra

Tags: modules, monoidal-categories, comodules

In the paper available: https://escholarship.org/uc/item/77r5k6cb

The differential is defined on page 13. Is this the wrong differential? Where are the $E_{p,q}$ maps coming from the twisted tensor differential?

To me it seems this is only a differential on the complex when $A$ is commutative but right below he seems to imply it works even when $A$ is not commutative.
Also, I computed $d^2$ for a small simple tensor and I did not get $0$ because the $a_i$ do not commute in $A$.